# Edge vs IE and the Facebook Like Button

Tags: internet-explorer, touchpad, microsoft-surface, microsoft-edge, microsoft-surface-pro

I am noticing a distinct behavior difference between Edge and IE.  In Facebook, if I use the trackpad to select "like" I am able to immediately click the "like choice" (opposed to angry, happy, etc).

In edge, however, I'm unable to click the like unless I wiggle the mouse.

That is annoying.

Does this mean that Edge isn't made for Trackpads?

Comment: No I don't think it means that Edge isn't made for Trackpads. It's probably some sort of buggy issue that Facebook may have. I'm sure they know about it, but it's possible that they don't. I would send them a [bug report](https://www.facebook.com/help/326603310765065/). It seems like typical IE/Edge non-sense really. We have all kinds of crazy bugs on our website as well. You should just use Chrome or Firefox instead :P

Comment: Are you using your Windows 10 as pc mode or tablet mode?

Comment: @AlejandraMoreno PC mode. Surface Book

Comment: @DrZoo Chrome eats up lots of battery, and is oddly slow in scrolling facebook.  Firefox, and Opera are my only choices left. (or legacy IE?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either is a bug with Edge and Facebook site or just Edge is corrupted.

Try to run this in PowerShell:

Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml" -Verbose}

Comment: help can you explain what this did? It fixed the issue

Comment: Reinstalls a built-in version of Microsoft Edge.